# Getting Current Reading of CIM_Tachometer in order to Get Fan Current Speed

Tags: c#, wmi, cim

I am working on a project which supposed to include computer's fans status. Most of the properties I need can be acquired from the `Win32_Fan` class. Sadly, I couldn't find a way to use this class for getting the current reading of the fan speed. In the [Win32_Fan MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394146(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) it is mentioned in the "DesiredSpeed" property that the current speed is determined by a sensor named `CIM_Tachometer`:

> **DesiredSpeed**
>
> Data type: **uint64**
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Qualifiers: Units ("revolutions per minute")
>
> Currently requested fan speed, defined in revolutions per minute, when
>   a variable speed fan is supported (VariableSpeed is TRUE). The current
>   speed is determined by a sensor (**CIM_Tachometer**) that is associated
>   with the fan using the **CIM_AssociatedSensor** relationship.
>
> This property is inherited from CIM_Fan.
>
> For more information about using uint64 values in scripts, see
>   Scripting in WMI.

After I saw that, I searched for this Tachometer CIM sensor and found the following code snippet (which was taken from http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/cim_tachometer/cs-samples.html):

```
//Project -> Add reference -> System.Management
//using System.Management;

//set the class name and namespace
string NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2";
string ClassName = "CIM_Tachometer";

//Create ManagementClass
ManagementClass oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);

//Get all instances of the class and enumerate them
foreach (ManagementObject oObject in oClass.GetInstances())
{
    //access a property of the Management object
    Console.WriteLine("Accuracy : {0}", oObject["Accuracy"]);
}
```

And so I tried implementing it in my code:

```
public static String[] GetFanInfo()
    {
        ManagementClass cSpeed = new ManagementClass
            ("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2:CIM_Tachometer");   //Create ManagementClass for the current speed property
        ManagementObjectSearcher temp = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
            "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature"); //Create management object searcher for the temperature property
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Fan"); //Create a management object searcher for the other properties
        string[] Id = new string[8]; //Preparig  a string array in which the results will be returned
        Id[0] = "Fan"; //First value is the category name
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {

            Id[1] = mo["Name"].ToString(); //Name of the component
            Id[2] = mo["Status"].ToString(); //Component's status
            long vel = Convert.ToInt64(mo["DesiredSpeed"]); //Desired speed of the component
            Id[4] = Convert.ToString(vel); 
            bool s = Convert.ToBoolean(mo["variableSpeed"]); //Wheater or not variable speed are supported
            Id[5] = s.ToString();
            break;
        }
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in temp.Get())
        {
            Double temperature = Convert.ToDouble(obj["CurrentTemperature"].ToString()); //Fetching the temperature
            Id[3] = Convert.ToString((temperature - 2732) / 10.0) + " C";
        }
        foreach (ManagementObject sObject in cSpeed.GetInstances()) //Get all instances of the class and enumerate them
        {
            Id[7] = sObject["CurrentReading"].ToString(); //Getting the current reading
        }
        return Id;
    }
```

To my surprise, it seems that the whole section of the current reading is skipped during runtime. occur anyway!

My question is, why is this certain part skipped? Is the Tachometer a sensor which cannot be used? is it disabled for some reason?

Thanks ahead.

P.S.

I'm writing the program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 using winforms for the user interface.

Comment: It is a standard issue with these low-level hardware WMI classes, they can only be as good as the provider that the machine manufacturer supplies.  Which in these days of cut-throat competition in the market segment is very hard to come by.  I don't think it is even possible anymore to pay enough to get them.  There are libraries out there that directly poke the chipset.  Tough shopping, nothing you'd particularly trust to run on any machine.

Comment: I see... I'm wondering how did the SpeedFan developer manage to do it.